# Specify environment variables from a file in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, spring-mvc, tomcat8

I have a setenv.sh file which contains environment variables of Spring MVC for Tomcat server. I can paste the file in Tomcat bin folder and run the application from terminal. But when I want to run it from Eclipse I should specify every variable separately. Is there a way to specify the path to the setenv.sh file from Eclipse so that Eclipse takes all the variables required from that file instead of specifying each and every variable separately?

Comment: In the upcoming Eclipse release, a bulk of environment variables can be copied or pasted in one go: https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.11/platform.php#env-var-copy-paste Would this be a solution for your problem?

Comment: Yes! This seems to be the solution to my problem. I will try it and reply you back. Thank you!